# Store user account information on a Windows Azure Table

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, oauth, azure-table-storage

Is there a quick way to store User Account information, extracted from Facebook or other providers, in a Window Azure Table?

Using Authentication on MVC 4, you can let your users log in to your website and then extract info to store it on a SQL Database. I was wondering if there's something similar to that but using Windows Azure Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is/was a Table Storage Membership Provider floating around a while ago.  I believe it may have been part of the samples in the Windows Azure Training Kit.  That may help provide a membership provider similar to the SQL provider you referenced.

As for Facebook data, that's going to be up to your application (get an auth token, retrieve user profile data from Facebook, store in your data store, etc.)

Comment: Exactly, the facebook data part it's not a problem, i'll look for that Table Storage Membership Provider. Thanks :)

Comment: I would be curious to see if the Membership Provider for Table Storage has been updated for the 2.0 storage SDK. Last time I used it, it was on 1.x series.